# cannot override styles in react-date-picker

Tags: reactjs, calendar, react-datepicker

I've gone through the usual recommendations. Next.js app with postcss, sass, and tailwind.

Trying to load styles from calendar.module.scss.

```
.react-datepicker {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #969eac;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Mulish';
}
.react-datepicker .react-datepicker__header  {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Even with !important, the above doesn't work. If I create a class of .calendar and apply that to my  component, I can at least get the main div to be styled.

```
import styles from './calendar.module.scss'
<ReactDatePicker
  inline
  calendarClassName={styles.calendar}
/>

// ./calendar.module.scss
.calendar {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #969eac;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: 'Mulish';
}
```

But trying to add the child classes to this has no effect. I tried adding the .react-datepicker classes to my style.css but that isn't having an effect either.

Curious if someone might have any pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran through the exact issue few days ago
I use SCSS with NEXT.js based react app, I will show you some code that will work if you are using material UI calendar
NOTE: this is dark theme customized calendar & pops up onClick with no textfield

```html
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider} from "@material-ui/pickers";
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Calendar.module.scss";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import {createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {black, white} from "material-ui/styles/colors";

export default function Calendar(props) {

    const materialTheme = createMuiTheme({
        palette: {
            primary: {
                main: '#3E3F42'
            }
        },
        overrides: {
            MuiPickersCalendarHeader: {
                switchHeader: {
                    backgroundColor: '#303235',
                    color: white,
                },
                iconButton: {
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    color: white
                },
                dayLabel: {
                    color: white //days in calendar
                },
                transitionContainer: {
                    color: white
                }
            },
            MuiPickersBasePicker: {
                pickerView: {
                    backgroundColor: '#3E3F42'
                }
            },
            MuiPickersDay: {
                day: {
                    color: white //days in calendar
                },
                  daySelected: {
                    backgroundColor: '#FFC561', //calendar circle
                      color: black
                  },
                  current: {
                    backgroundColor: '#736F69',
                      color: white
                  },
            },

            MuiDialogActions: {
                root: {
                    backgroundColor: '#3E3F42'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    const isOpened = props.isOpened;
    const topPosition = props.topPosition;
    const selectedDate = props.selectedDate;

    const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
    }

    async function handleDateChange(date1) {
        props.onChange(date1);
        await sleep(700);
        props.setDDOpen(false);
    }

    return isOpened ? (
            <Box pad={{ vertical: 'small'}} className={styles.smallCard} style={{top: topPosition}}>
                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                    <MuiThemeProvider theme={materialTheme}>
                    <DatePicker
                        disableToolbar
                        variant="static"
                        value={selectedDate}
                        onChange={handleDateChange}
                    />
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
            </Box>): null
}
```